# FlutterPluginBinding.flutterEngine is deprecated

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-plugin

I develop a **Flutter** plugin, the problem is `FlutterPluginBinding.flutterEngine` to get `FlutterEngine` is deprecated. Full code is below:

```
class AMPlugin : FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware, PluginRegistry.ActivityResultListener {
    private lateinit var channel: MethodChannel
    private var activity: Activity? = null

    override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        val engine = flutterPluginBinding.flutterEngine
        channel = MethodChannel(engine.dartExecutor, "aM")
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
    }

    override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
        when (call.method) {
            else -> result.notImplemented()
        }
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromActivity() {
        activity = null
    }

    override fun onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        activity = binding.activity
    }

    override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        activity = binding.activity
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {
        activity = null
    }

    companion object {

        @Suppress("UNUSED")
        @JvmStatic
        fun registerWith(registrar: Registrar) {
            val channel = MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "aM")
            channel.setMethodCallHandler(AMPlugin())
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't understand how to get `FlutterEngine` or initialize `MethodChannel` in another way. I tried as `val engine = FlutterEngine(binding.applicationContext)` but it leads to the crash, seems it requires `Activity` context.

How to replace this deprecated API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace:

```
    channel = MethodChannel(engine.dartExecutor, "aM")
```

with

```
    channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getBinaryMessenger(), "aM")
```

Comment: Thank you very much!